# react : Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a fetch request to a local json file and I get this error saying `Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` pointing at `response.json()`. I tried adding proxy package.json but i get 500 internal error. How can I solve this?

```js
componentDidMount() {    
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/items.json')
  .then(function(response) {
    if (response.status >= 400) {
      throw new Error("Bad response");
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  });
}
```

json file:

```js
[
  {
    data: [
      {
        name: "cnt",
        level: "12"
      },
      {
        name: "stewart",
        level: "6"
      },
      {
        name: "nic",
        level: "7"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: What is your backend part?

Comment: i'm using create react app. i'm doing the fetch within app.js

Comment: Which folder is your file located at?

Comment: json is within the `src` folder and within the src folder i have app.js.

Comment: If it's just create react app then there is no other backend running that can serve your JSON file. Consider importing it with Webpack instead. `import obj from './items.json'`. If you put the file in the `public` folder, you will be able to get it from the same origin: `fetch('/items.json')`

Comment: i tried both and then `fetch('/items.json')` worked in public folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Create React App then there is no other backend running that can serve your JSON file. Consider importing it with Webpack instead.

```js
import data from './items.json';

class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {    
    console.log(data);
  }
  // ...
}
```

Alternatively, you could put the file in the `public` folder and you will be able to get it from the same origin.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("/items.json")
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("Bad response");
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => console.log(data))
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your file to `public` folder instead of `src`.